# Burninate [bound] and [unbound]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request

I just browsed at some questions when I noticed [bound](/questions/tagged/bound). Apparently, this tag is useless (one reason: no wiki) and is often irrelevant to the questions where it is used.

**EDIT**: I'll include [unbound](/questions/tagged/unbound) for the same reasons as that of [bound](/questions/tagged/bound). (They should burn together!)

I therefore humbly open up a discussion on whether these tag should be burninated or left as is.

Comment: Just 50 post with that tag ...even its easy to go through each and remove tag

Comment: @NullPointer Sorry. I'm not that diligent. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These tags have been BURNiNATED!

I went through the last 25 or so [bound](/questions/tagged/bound) questions and all of the [unbound](/questions/tagged/unbound) questions, so they will both magically disappear from the system in 24 hours.

[image: TROGGY]

Answer (score 3):

I agree. It looks like a meta tag to me (can't exist independently).

Comment: Thank you for giving the term "meta tag". Now I have a "formal term" for those kind of tags. :)

Comment: While I'm not sure we need those tags, I don't see how they're meta tags.  They are specific programming terms.