# Should we destroy the [bounding], [inbound], and [outbound] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I came across three tags the other day while [Burninating [bound] and [unbound]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172129/burninate-bound-and-unbound), that didn't really make sense, and decided to ask you guys before nuking them myself.

The tags in question are:

- [bounding](/questions/tagged/bounding) (x26)
- [inbound](/questions/tagged/inbound) (x25)
- [outbound](/questions/tagged/outbound) (x38, with a wiki)

With the exception of outbound, none of the tags have a tag wiki, and <s>[only one orphaned question would remain](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/103661/)</s> no orphaned questions would remain, which makes me believe they cannot stand on their own and should be sent the way of the dodo.

So, may I pull out the magical fires of troggy and burn these tags to the ground?

Comment: Changed to none which would be orphaned.

Answer (score 1):

They may not be useful tags, but they are not meta-tags, just like [bound](/questions/tagged/bound) and [unbound](/questions/tagged/unbound) were not meta-tags.

**Meta tags are tags about the type or kind of question, instead of the content.**

These are all technical terms that would refer to the content.  So they aren't meta-tags, though I think they're probably too broad to be good tags, and few would do a tag search based on them.

Specifically:

[bounding](/questions/tagged/bounding) should be synonymed to [bounding-box](/questions/tagged/bounding-box)

[outbound](/questions/tagged/outbound) I would probably create an [outbound-links](/questions/tagged/outbound-links) and synonym to it

[inbound](/questions/tagged/inbound) I'd burn that one

Comment: Alright, I updated the original question to remove the meta-tag thing. I think your post made that clear. Although, it would be nice to see some official terminology for terms like that.

Comment: Really, though, does `outbound-links` solve anything? I question whether or not it means anything - after all, isn't the purpose of a tag to help you find experts in that domain? I highly question the ability to be an expert in outbound links.

Comment: OK, I'll leave the definition in my answer for those who come behind.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, no, that's not the __only__ purpose.  It's also to help you search the question space to find the posts you need to solve your problem.  So a web-developer with a specific outbound-link problem might find it handy.  To be really sure I'd probably have to go through all the outbound tagged questions, and I don't really have time to do that, but if you go through them you'll have it figured out by the time your done.  I've done a lot of retagging projects, and they're always very educational.

Comment: the real question then becomes at what point don't they help? We could tag almost every question on the site with 'development', just to improve 'searchability', if we wanted to. My point here is that they are very small, don't refer to a specific technology and really aren't answerable on their own, and as such should probably be deleted. I could understand creating a synonym for `bounding`, but I'm really not getting the `outbound` one.

Comment: No, the more specific that tags the better, and 'development' would cover every question on the site, so it's probably a little broad.  Since web development isn't my area, I myself would err on the side of caution, but if you have more expertise in the area, and how people might want to search for that kind of question, then you might have a better idea on it.  The goal in retagging is to make the site better and more usable, hopefully others will chime in with more input.